# Python re.IGNORECASE being dynamic

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to do something like this:

```
re.findall(r"(?:(?:\A|\W)" + 'Hello' + r"(?:\Z|\W))", 'hello world',re.I)
```

And have re.I be dynamic, so I can do case-sensitive or insensitive comparisons on the fly.  This works but is undocumented:

```
re.findall(r"(?:(?:\A|\W)" + 'Hello' + r"(?:\Z|\W))", 'hello world',1)
```

To set it to sensitive.  Is there a Pythonic way to do this?  My best thought so far is:

```
if case_sensitive:
   regex_senstive = 1
else:
   regex_sensitive = re.I
re.findall(r"(?:(?:\A|\W)" + 'Hello' + r"(?:\Z|\W))", 'hello world',regex_sensitive)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the default behavior, you can use `0` for the flags parameter. You should not use `1`, as it will set the undocumented `re.TEMPLATE` flag, which disables backtracking.

So you can use:

```
flags = 0 if case_sensitive else re.I
re.findall(r'pattern', s, flags)
```

The flags parameter is actually a combination of flags (`re.I`, `re.M`, etc.), with each flag represented by a single bit. When no bits are set (the value 0), the default behavior is used.

Comment: Is the default behavior reliably case-sensitive?